# Target Blank is not working for wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am using HTML with PHP, I want to open the downloadable file for the new window but am not able to do it. please help me. I have given below my code.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);"  target="_blank"><?php echo wp_get_attachment_link($print->fileupload, true);?></a>
```

Comment: try this  if you are using jquery <a onclick="window.open ('yourlink', ''); return false" href="javascript:void(0);"></a>

Answer (score 0):

`<a href="javascript:void(0);">` will halt any action. So `target="_blank"` is ignored. You need an onClick function for it to do anything. Try:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" target="_blank" onClick="window.open('https://www.website.com')";><?php echo wp_get_attachment_link($print->fileupload, true);?></a>
```